# 2 deleted answers with bounties; only one linked in profile's "Earned bounties" tab

Tags: support, profile-page, bounty, deleted-questions

I noticed a bit of inconsistency when it comes to bounties on answers that got deleted *(or more accurately, questions that got deleted along with the answers that earned a bounty)*.

Here is one case, where [a user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243437/why-did-i-lose-my-500-bounty-after-a-question-got-deleted?noredirect=1&lq=1) earned a bounty from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26563368/13552470) *(10K+ link)* that later got deleted:

[image]

I [can see](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4021394/chantola?tab=bounties) the "1 Earned bounty", but not the link to the deleted post.

However, on [this other user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447356/shadow-the-vaccinated-wizard?tab=bounties), [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461339/where-can-i-find-official-canonical-documentation-for-using-javascript-with-c) *(10K+ link)* is visible to the deleted post they earned a bounty on:

[image]

Why does the first case not provide the link to the deleted post, while the other case does? Could the reason be that the one that isn't visible in the user's profile was deleted by a CM, while the one that's visible was deleted by fellow users? <sub>This is likely irrelevant, but the bounties in both cases were 500 rep.</sub>

Comment: FWIW as a <10k user, the pages show 0 and 2 earned bounties respectively

Answer (score 3):

My guess is it has something to do with the system feature that locks in rep for deleted post is at play here.

From [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/253521):

> - First, reputation earned for posts with a score of 3 or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained. This does not include reputation lost from giving bounties on them (this will be nullified as normal).
> - Second, if a question that has had bounties awarded to answers is deleted, and one or more of the answers would get to retain their reputation per the above first exception, the bounty reputation given to those answers will not be refunded to the bounty owner(s).

The one you can still see was deleted after 3 months had passed, and the score was >= 3, so the system retained the rep gain records for that post.

However, the one that isn't visible from the user's timeline was deleted within 3 months, so its rep gain events were not retained by the system.

So even though the post rep was retained in the first situation, the bounty rep wasn't, even though still recorded the bounty *event*. Honestly... not sure.